# What are the best pen and ink or woodblock print photoshop actions / effects out there?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I have searched for a while but the results seem slim, I have only found this:

- https://elements.envato.com/pen-sketch-photoshop-action-UGCFS3

However, I would like to take any photograph or illustration (JPG) and convert it into a pen and ink or woodblock style image that look along the lines of these:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Are there any effects or actions out there that could do that to a regular photograph? Or something close enough?

Comment: You might try luck with ai filters ('replace style' neural networks) but there are no actions that can convert photos to believable handdrawn pieces

Comment: Doesn't have to be "believable" necessarily, just anything along these lines tho.

Comment: Well, the bottom two images are **not** some filter. They are *clearly* manually created in my opinion. Top image is a little iffy.. could be a filter I suppose, but I suspect that's a manual creation as well. Most *good* woodcut or linocut art is done by hand. Filters ... look like.. well filters. but there is EngraverPro for Photoshop.

Comment: Your earlier question Aug 5 '19 at 4:12 got some response that can be useful now. Do not expect any filter replaces well done handcrafting. Filters proceed locally, they cannot see the big picture. By filtering visible objects separately with proper selections you can get something which resembles manual work.